# Nested cross validation for Lassocv

Tags: python, machine-learning, cross-validation

I'm new to Python and learning the ISLR book. in it I'm looking at the boston dataset and trying different models.
One of them is the LassoCV from sklearn.
I read here the importance of a nested loop and found the optimal lambda from the training data set.
[See here the link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html)
I'm trying to understand how I can use this specific lambda to see the MSE for the test data set.
Please help!
Here is my code:

```
##importing packages

    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, LassoCV, RidgeCV
    import statsmodels.api as sm
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
    from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, train_test_split
    from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
    bos = load_boston()

##creating the dataset

    boston = pd.DataFrame(bos.data)
    boston.columns = bos.feature_names

##defining X,y and spliting to train and test data

    y = boston['CRIM']
    X = boston.drop('CRIM',axis=1)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

##Lassocv first loop function
    lassocv =LassoCV(alphas=np.logspace(-5,-2.5,300),cv=5,normalize=True,max_iter=10000) #normalize functions as scale
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    lassocv.fit(X_train,y_train)
    mses = np.mean(lassocv.mse_path_,axis=1)
    alphas = lassocv.alphas_
    min_alpha = lassocv.alpha_
    min_mse = np.min(mses)
```

Now that I have the right lambda, how do I incorporate it in to check the MSE for the test data?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the metrics from sklearn.

[MSE metric](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html)

You can use the code:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
y_pred = lassocv.predict(y_test)
print('MSE', mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
```

Comment: Thanks but how is this letting me incorporate the lambda I found from the previous cross validation?
Please explain